# iconvlist() inconsistency on alpine linux

Tags: r, encoding, utf-8

I have a docker container set up that is based on `artemklevtsov/r-alpine:latest`. When I run my `R` scripts I see this error:

`Invalid encoding UTF-8: defaulting to UTF-8.`

I tracked this down to this code in the httr library:
https://github.com/hadley/httr/blob/master/R/content-parse.r#L5

It looks like `iconvlist()` on alpine returns encodings that have a trailing comma at the end, ex:

```
iconvlist()
 [1] "..."        "ISO8859-1," "ISO8859-2," "ISO8859-3," "ISO8859-4,"
 [6] "ISO8859-5," "ISO8859-6," "ISO8859-7," "UCS-2BE,"   "UCS-2LE,"
[11] "US_ASCII,"  "UTF-16BE,"  "UTF-16LE,"  "UTF-32BE,"  "UTF-8,"
```

Therefore `UTF-8` never matches `UTF-8,`. Has anyone ran into this issue before? The list of encodings I get on my local Mac (OSX) is correct and doesn't have trailing commas. It also doesn't happen on CentOS, so it looks like it's specific to alpine.

Is there a way to get around this? Maybe through a configuration in `R` or by modifying the `iconvlist()` output?

Comment: This is fixed in R >= 4.0.4, thanks to a report at <https://bugs.r-project.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17970>.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same issue, this time from calling `read::read_csv`, which uses `base::iconvlist` and gives the same error message `Invalid encoding UTF-8: defaulting to UTF-8.`. This is on `alpine:3.12` using R 3.6.3 provided by `apk add R` and, based on the details below, I think the issue will be present on *any* version of alpine and R unless steps have been taken to address it directly.

I found a couple of solutions. TLDR:

1. Remove the commas from the file at `system.file("iconvlist", package = "utils")`, or
2. Recompile R using the gnu-libiconv library for more comprehensive `iconv` support.

### Solution 1

The `base::iconvlist()` function uses an `iconvlist` file as a fallback method to get the list of encodings the system supports. On alpine this fallback method will always be used, for reasons outlined below, but the `iconvlist` file has commas in, which R is not expecting.

The easiest solution is to remove the commas from the `iconvlist` file, which can be found with `base::system.file()`.

```r
> system.file("iconvlist", package = "utils")
[1] "/usr/lib/R/library/utils/iconvlist"
```

One way to remove the commas, from the command line (not R) is:

```sh
sed -i 's/,//g' /usr/lib/R/library/utils/iconvlist
```

Subsequent calls to `base::iconvlist()` will read and parse the new file without the commas, and other functions that rely on `base::iconvlist()` will be able to successfully check for support, e.g. for "UTF-8".

```r
> iconvlist()
 [1] "..."       "ISO8859-1" "ISO8859-2" "ISO8859-3" "ISO8859-4" "ISO8859-5"
 [7] "ISO8859-6" "ISO8859-7" "UCS-2BE"   "UCS-2LE"   "US_ASCII"  "UTF-16BE" 
[13] "UTF-16LE"  "UTF-32BE"  "UTF-8"     "UTF32-LE"  "WCHAR_T"

> "UTF-8" %in% iconvlist()
[1] TRUE
```

#### Why is this necessary?

International conversion (`iconv`) of character encodings is a feature that R expects to be provided by the operating system, stipulated in the [R Administration and Installation Manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-admin.html#Essential-programs-and-libraries). Operating systems provide their own implementations of `iconv` functionality, sometimes with fewer features. Since alpine is designed to be minimal, it is not surprising that it provides only what is necessary to meet the POSIX standards.

When R is built on a system it first checks the extent of `iconv` support from the host's C development libraries, before it compiles features into R's internals. Crucially, support for the **C function** `iconvlist` is checked for, which is not present on alpine, as shown in the apk [build log](https://build.alpinelinux.org/buildlogs/build-3-12-x86_64/community/R/R-3.6.3-r2.log) for R: `checking for iconvlist... no`, so this C function is not available to R internally.

R's `base::iconvlist()` function will first try to get encodings using pre-compiled C code via `.Internal(iconv(...`, which will call `iconvlist` (in C) if available. As the `iconvlist` C function is not present on alpine, this `.Internal` call will always return NULL, and the R function will fall back to reading the info from the `iconvlist` file:

```r
> iconvlist
function () 
{
    int <- .Internal(iconv(NULL, "", "", "", TRUE, FALSE))
    if (length(int)) 
        return(sort.int(int))
    icfile <- system.file("iconvlist", package = "utils")
# ... (truncated)
```

#### Why is the `iconvlist` file in an unexpected format?

The `iconvlist` file is created when R is [built](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/utils/Makefile.in), from the command `iconv -l` which lists the available encodings. This is the utility program at `/usr/bin/iconv` *not* an R or C function. There is no standard for the format of the output of `iconv -l`. Alpine tries to conform to [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standards, and these only require that the `-l` option writes "values to standard output in an unspecified format".

R is expecting the file format to contain values separated by spaces (`base::iconvlist()` parses the file with `strsplit(ext, "[[:space:]]")`), which is true for other Linux variants, e.g. Debian, CentOS, but not for alpine's musl libc [version](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/blame/main/musl/iconv.c), which has the commas.

### Solution 2

A more rigorous solution is to build R from source using an alternative `iconv` C library implementation that provides the `iconvlist` C function. `base::iconvlist()` can then fetch the encodings via its `.Internal(iconv(...` call, and never needs to fall back to the `iconvlist` file.

An implementation that provides `iconvlist` is GNU [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/), which has been packaged for alpine and can be installed with:

```sh
apk add gnu-libiconv gnu-libiconv-dev
```

The package `gnu-libiconv-dev` provides headers in `/usr/include/gnu-libiconv/`, so the compiler needs to be pointed here in preference to the existing ones in `/usr/include`. This is outside my expertise but can be done by adding `-I/usr/include/gnu-libiconv` to the `CFLAGS` environment variable.

```sh
export CFLAGS=-I/usr/include/gnu-libiconv $CFLAGS
```

Running `./configure` should yield check results similar to:

```sh
... (truncated)
checking for iconv.h... yes
checking for iconv... in libiconv
checking whether iconv accepts "UTF-8", "latin1", "ASCII" and "UCS-*"... yes
checking whether iconv accepts "CP1252"... yes
checking for iconvlist... yes
... (truncated)
```

After `make` I can run `./bin/R` and, even if the `iconvlist` file still contains commas, calls to `base::iconvlist()` yields well-formatted results:

```r
> iconvlist()
  [1] "850"                                          
  [2] "862"                                          
  [3] "866"                                          
  [4] "ANSI_X3.4-1968"                               
  [5] "ANSI_X3.4-1986"
... (truncated)

# The unsorted list is coming from the internal C functions, not the file
> .Internal(iconv(NULL, "", "", "", TRUE, FALSE))
  [1] "ANSI_X3.4-1968"                               
  [2] "ANSI_X3.4-1986"                               
  [3] "ASCII"                                        
  [4] "CP367"                                        
  [5] "IBM367"
... (truncated)
```